# How to detect the circular Gestures on New Siri Remote 2nd Generation

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, siri-remote

I want to detect the action of rotate the wheel on the new Apple TV Siri Remote 2nd Generation.

Is there a way to know which direction clockwise or anti-clockwise?

How can i get the speed of rotation or any data related to this circular action?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple did not announce any new gesture recognizer for this new gesture, but you can implement it by yourself.

To do it you can use the GameController SDK that will allow you to get the absolute location of the user finger in the digitizer. Once you have the coordinates of the gesture location you can apply some trigonometry maths to detect if they are rotating the finger clockwise or anticlockwise.

I wrote a post with further details here:
https://dcordero.me/posts/capture_circular_gestures_on_siri_remote_2nd_generation.html